# How to delete characters from a text box based on numeric up down value in C#?

Tags: c#

I have these two fields:

[image]

On load - the default value is 4.

I am aiming to cast the product code text box based on the numeric number selected.

**Example**

From the example above, this should be the output:

[image]

If I set it to 2 it should be this:

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productCode.Text = (productCode.Text.Substring(0, productCode.Text.Length - numericUpDown1.Value));
}
```

**Error**

```
Cannot convert from decimal to int
```

**Also...**

I have tested this:

```
productCode.Text = (productCode.Text.Substring(0, productCode.Text.Length - 4));
```

It errors me out if I apply it multiple times:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.
```

**Question**

What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Cast to int... -> `productCode.Text = (productCode.Text.Substring(0, productCode.Text.Length - (int)numericUpDown1.Value));`. Also you should write the code to handle ArgumentOutOfRangeException if you are using `Substring` for ex - when the text is empty or does not have the length which is being subtracted.

Comment: Replace the code in the `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` event with `var s =  productCode.Text.TrimStart('0'); productCode.Text = s.PadLeft((int)numericUpDown1.Value + s.Length, '0');`

Comment: @dr.null Thank you for your other response :) This code you have given me, adds extra zeros as a prefix. I am trying to remove characters from the right depending on the numeric up and down selected value. So as an example `Value: '1234'` Pad `PadVal: 2` this turns out to `Value: 12` because `34` are removed.

Comment: ah, sorry I thought you need leading zeros. Let me check.

Comment: Try the answer below (by Mike) + a length check to avoid throwing an exception: `var s = productCode.Text; var len = (int)numericUpDown1.Value; productCode.Text = s.Substring(0, s.Length > len ? len : s.Length);`

Comment: @dr.null I'll have a go when I am back at work next morning :D

Comment: @dr.null Hello, nope it doesn't work. I'll find an alternative.

Comment: @LV98 did my answer not solve your issue? In that case could you please comment why it did not work? :-)  or atleast what you error you hit when applying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at your example i think this is one way to do it:

```
private string originalProductCode = "0001050OL"; //Set this if productcode changes


private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productCode.Text = (originalProductCode.Substring(0, (int)numericUpDown1.Value));
}
```

Comment: The Original Product Code will depend on user input. It's not always going to stay as `0001050OL` I can type something like this as an example: `Hello World!`. And from there the numeric up and down will determine how many characters to remove.

Comment: @LV98 i have provided you with minimal code that should solve your problem. You should be able to figure out yourself how to change the originalProductCode variable with another method. That could for example be a private void productCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }.